# Getting error when trying to convert milliseconds to date

Tags: php, date

I'm trying to convert `[lastViewedAt] => 1329939559` into the date format `YYYY-MM-DD, HH:MM`, but I'm getting this error message every time I try:

```
Warning: gmdate() expects parameter 2 to be long, object given in ...
```

If I write the milliseconds (copy > paste) in plain text in my function it works. Instead of

```
gmdate('Y-m-d, H:i', $information['lastViewedAt'])
```

the following:

```
gmdate('Y-m-d, H:i', '1329939559')
```

I'll get the proper result of it - 2012-02-22, 19:39. Why am I seeing this behaviour?

Comment: What do you get when you `var_dump($information['lastViewedAt']);`?

Comment: @jprofitt: `object(SimpleXMLElement)[9] string '1329940225' (length=10)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cast your SimpleXMLElement's contents to a string or a long:

```
gmdate('Y-m-d, H:i', (int)$information['lastViewedAt'])
```

Comment: Probably best to cast as an `(int)`.

Comment: @HighwayofLife I couldn't remember if it was (int) or (integer) offhand, so I went with string. :-)

Answer (score -1):

Why dont you use the date function instead? Like this

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i',$information['lastViewedAt']);
```

Comment: gmdate is just a GMT version of the date function. The same issue will be present there.

Comment: Just saw the output of you var_dump and @ceejayoz is totally correct, you need to cast the SimpleXMLElement Object. Although according to the php documentation the second parameter should be an integer so I think casting to integer will be more appropriate. i.e `gmdate('Y-m-d, H:i', (int)$information['lastViewedAt'])`